# change column name in sql server without using sp_rename

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to change my column name in sql server using a query, without using `sp_rename` command. Can you please tell me if anybody know it?

I tried as:

```
alter table table_name alter column 'column1' to 'column2'
```

and it gave an error message as:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'column1'.
```

Comment: If you have SSMS, you can highlight the table, press F2, and rename it that way.

Comment: `'column1'` is a character *literal*, **not** an identifier. Remove the single quotes. See the manual for details on what an identifier is: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: You may *want* to use an alternative, but the only one I can think of would involve poking around in the system tables and wouldn't be supported. The SQL Standard is the `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME` form but SQL Server doesn't implement it. The only supported way is `sp_rename`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to rename a column using the ALTER TABLE statement in SQL Server. [**Reference**](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/alter-table-rename-column.html).

Use sp_rename instead.

**OR**

You can right click on the table -> select rename -> type new name.

And example is [**here**](http://sqlandme.com/2013/03/04/sql-server-how-to-rename-tablecolumn-in-sql-server/).

Comment: it is giving an error message as Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'rename'.

Comment: alter table dbo.dvs rename column fullname to name;

Comment: i'm asking you the sql server query. not in the database explorer.

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table table_name add column 'column2'
update table_name set column2 = column1
alter table table_name drop column column1
```

PSEUDOCODE, need data types, likely to turn off triggers, etc.  Quite ugly, but does "get the job done".
NOT very good for large tables, of course...